# Trouble updating Android Market to Google Play on Logitech-Revue (Google-TV)

Tags: google-play-store, google-tv, logitech-revue

When I try to go into the Android Market on my Logitech-Revue it says it needs to update, but never does. On my Acer A500 tablet the Android Market updated to Google Play, so I assume that is the update that my Revue is attempting, but failing.

Anyone else successful with the Google Play update on Logitech-Review or Google TV? Any suggestions for a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally updated. Not sure what the hang up was before.